# jQuery Mobile dialog code isn't showing up in the source unless it comes first?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have two jQuery mobile pages, one is a normal page and one is a dialog. The dialog won't show up in the html at all (examining the source in a browser) when the application is run unless it comes first, in which case the page is the dialog instead of the page I want it to be.

This is currently what's inside the body:

```
<!-- main page -->
<div data-role="page" id="play-game">
      <style>
          .ui-mobile .ui-page {
              background : transparent;
          }
          body.ui-mobile-viewport {
              background: url(images/image.jpg);
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              background-position:center center;
              background-attachment:scroll;
              background-size:100% 100%;
          }
      </style>
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>Timer: </h1><div id="time"><h1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">Score: <div id="score">0</div></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Dialog I'm trying to show -->
  <div data-role="page" data-rel="dialog" id="gameover">
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Game Over!</h1>
       </div><!-- /header -->
       <div data-role="content">
           <p>I'm second in the source order so I'm not shown as the page initally.</p>
       </div><!-- /content -->
       <div data-role="footer">
           <h4>Page Footer</h4>
       </div><!-- /footer -->
   </div><!-- /page -->
```

I'm trying to get it to popup from a javascript file using:

```
   $.mobile.changePage( $("#gameover"));
```

or

```
   $("#gameover").popup('open');
```

which was something else I was using earlier.

Essentially what's happening is that both those jQuery calls are finding undefined pages because the page just isn't there for some inexplicable reason. If it's relevant, I'm using netbeans and both safari and firefox.

Thanks for any advice/help you can give me!

Edit: At request, here is a simple jsfiddle that works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/Y7744/4/. Note: in the actual program I'm calling the popup from a function outside the main file.

Comment: can you add a simple example into jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7744/4/. I'm calling the popup after 3 seconds just for the sake of example. In my program it's called from a function.

Comment: are your pages in your real application deep with in the DOM? you can remove the $('') from your call to `$.mobile.changePage( "#gameover")`

Comment: To be clear, the second page isn't showing up at all when the application is run. What works in the jsfiddle is:     `$.mobile.changePage('#gameover','pop',false,true);` The actual application fails to see any page with id "#gameover" at all. Safari tells me `$("gameover")` is undefined.

Comment: I figured it out, sort of. I've been moving things around in this project getting a feel for jQuery mobile and my javascript file is linked to the wrong page, i.e. not where gameover is located. So the page I was looking at in my code was incorrect. The gameover page should have been located on a different html page. Thanks for your help.